# Use Play! with a graph-visualization framework that relies on Servlets

Tags: servlets, graph, playframework

I really like Play and it adresses all the problems I had when develpoing web applications. My next project involves calculations on graphs (in this case biological networks) and visualization of large graphs. All the 'backend' stuff is done with the [JUNG Graph API](http://jung.sourceforge.net/), which can be easily integrated in a Play project.

I used to do graph visualization in web applications with [yFiles AJAX from yWorks](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfilesajax_about.html). You will most likely know yWorks if you have ever worked with graphs in Java. yFiles AJAX is basically a JAVA/JavaScript library that offers:

a) Server components that hold the graph model. They mostly extend the extend the Java Servlet API.
b) Client side components that display the graph. This is based on Dojo, which should work in Play.

The components are discribed in detail here: [yFiles AJAX dev guide](http://docs.yworks.com/yfilesajax/doc/devguide/index.html#components)

I know that Play does not use the Servlet API for many good reasons. My question is more general, because I am not that experienced with Play or other frameworks:

Can I use something like yFiles AJAX, which relies on servlets, inside a Play application? Or do I have to stick to a basic JAVA EE project with servlets/jsps?

I hope you understand my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your API and apparently it heavily relies on servlets everywhere.
I'm not even sure that they provide the code for those server parts...
So in this case, I'm not sure that the servlets are just facade that call backend services. From what I can see in the doc, it doesn't seem to be the case.

Therefore, I think it would be better to keep this module besides Play and not to try to put it into Play, you will spend long time.

Nevertheless, there are some business modules used by the servlets clearly identified in the doc so I think that with some work, it could be modified and become a play module. But how long would it take??? I don't know ;)

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right. The API is extensive and I'm going to use much of it. So I will have to stick to good old servlets here.

Comment: at least they used servlets and not a big framework in front of it... To my mind, the road to Play might be shorter from this than from JSF or other heavy things :)... Anyway, if you're in a hurry, use the servlets for your graphs. Even if I don't know your application, I think nothing prevents you from using Play in parallel and integrate external graphs into play web pages.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do. I will implement everything in Play and build an independent application for the graphs. I can use that for some other projects. You answer all my Play questions, do you work with it regularly?

Comment: I'm not a play developer, I contribute quite a lot to the group, I use it a lot but not professionally yet even if I'd like but the Java industry is still in the 5years old techno :)... For a few months now, I'm the main committer in project Siena (www.sienaproject.com - the website is a bit outdated & need more doc), an DB-object-mapping API bridging SQL/NoSQL and a nice alternative to JPA/JDO for MySQL/Postgres/GAE(and other NoSQL soon), active record oriented and providing an integration with Play!... give it a try and don't hesitate to contact me if you have any problem or questions...

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it won't be simple (possible, yes, simple, not by far). The first issue would be to encapsulate the Play application in a Servlet environment (which would somehow defeat the purpose of using Play).

The second is that Play is Stateless (one of the [reasons](http://iam.guillaume.bort.fr/post/558830013/why-there-is-no-servlets-in-play) why Servlets were dropped), which (probably) would not go nicely with your library if it relies on state (like Session).

Comment: I know, they dropped servlets for a reason ;) I think I will stick to a simple web app without Play.